# deleting data of more than one table through sql query in sql-server

Tags: sql-server, delete-row

i have a master table `Staff`. i have other table also such as `staffStudy`, `StaffPenison`, `visitInfo` etc. i haven't made any relation between these table. i want to know that if I delete the Staff table then is it possible to delete all the information of that staff from other tables? `Staff_id` is use to represent the information of particular staff. any help appreciated.

Comment: You can write a trigger to manually do the DELETE on the other tables.

Comment: @Sparkey i am using a program and i will like to fire query in button click event. i think it would not be possible with the trigger isn't it?

Comment: The trigger is done at the database level, so it will occur whenever the DELETE takes place.  So if the code behind the button Click deletes from STAFF, the other rows will be deleted as well

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a stored procedure that deletes from the 12 tables.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.Staff_Delete
    @Staff_ID INT
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    BEGIN TRANSACTION;

    BEGIN TRY
      DELETE dbo.VisitInfo WHERE Staff_ID = @Staff_ID;
      DELETE dbo.StaffPension WHERE Staff_ID = @Staff_ID;
      DELETE dbo.StaffStudy WHERE Staff_ID = @Staff_ID;
      /* ...other tables... */
      DELETE dbo.Staff WHERE Staff_ID = @Staff_ID;
      COMMIT TRANSACTION;
    END TRY
    BEGIN CATCH
      ROLLBACK TRANSACTION;
    END CATCH
END
GO
```

Now your button click event can just call this stored procedure, and if you add tables to the model, you just have to change the procedure instead of changing all copies of the application.

It seems strange that you wouldn't have foreign key relationships here; while I agree with others that cascade doesn't belong in production, so it wouldn't help solve this specific problem, but FK constraints are useful for many other reasons. Was this a conscious choice?

Answer (score -1):

The following is a sample trigger.

```
CREATE TRIGGER Delete_Staff_tables
ON Staff
FOR DELETE
AS
BEGIN
   DECLARE @StaffID INT
   SELECT @StaffID = Staff_ID FROM Deleted
   DELETE FROM StaffStudy WHERE staff_ID = @StaffID
   DELETE FROM StaffPension WHERE staff_ID = @StaffID
   -- Etc
END
```

However, be sure it makes business sense to delete the child tables.   If a Staff member leaves (and is deleted), he might get mighty upset if he loses his pension too.

**Additional comments**
As Mitch suggested, putting the additional deletes in Client code makes sense, because the database trigger could cause some deletions other programmers might not be aware of.  However, if you do the 12 additional queries in your client code, be sure to wrap them in a transaction.  What would be the impact on your system if 3-6 of the delete queries succeeded, but the others didn't?

Comment: 2 points: don't use triggers for deletions like this, it's too dangerous to delete data this way (as you say, deleting a pension would be bad). Also, your trigger does not take into account multiple rows.

Comment: Why do you feel it is dangerous?  I'd rather have the DELETE performed at the database than in client code?  I agree though, the business implications need to be considered.   You are right, I am assuming the staff_ID field is a unique field in the staff table, and it might not be...  Thanks for pointing that out...

Comment: That's not what I meant by multiple rows: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190752(SQL.110).aspx

Comment: More often than not, deletes are better performed in client code, where it is explicitly performed rather than hidden.

Comment: Or he could define a relationship between the tables and let SQL handle it...   But I see your concern that anyone working on the code might not be aware of the database impact when they write code that they think is only delete record(s) from a single table...

Comment: exactly. I never use cascading deletes in production Databases, for that reason.

Comment: thanks both of you i get more idea on this. now i should fire 12 Query for deleting the record from 12 tables.

Comment: I guess backend programmers should think about the front-end developers as well..   Thanks for the good discussion...

Comment: yes the whole conversation was informative. it would have more easy if we have the simple code as delete * from tableA,TableB.....where .....

Comment: You could also write a stored procedure called   DeleteStaffFromAllTables and pass it the Staff ID.   At least it will be clear what will happen if someone runs the procedure...

Comment: As Mich Weat pointed out, this trigger will take into account only deletions of one row (and one `Staff_IDs`) from `Staff` table (`... FOR Staff AFTER DELETE ...`). So, if somebody delete two ore more rows (two or more `Staff_IDs`) from `Staff` table then this trigger will, still, delete only rows for **one** `Staff_ID` from StaffStudy and StaffPension tables. This is [RBAR](http://www.simple-talk.com/sql/t-sql-programming/rbar--row-by-agonizing-row/) approach.

Comment: @Bogdan it isn't RBAR unless you add a cursor and loop through the id values in the deleted pseudo-table. As it is it is just incorrect because the id that gets deleted will be an arbitrary one, and the rest will become orphaned rows.

Comment: @Aaron: (1) please take a look at "RBAR in a trigger" section from  article mentioned in my last comment. (2) Totally agree. And these consequences (orphaned rows) are possible because there is no relation between tables or trigger to check referential integrity.

Comment: @Bogdan the RBAR he's talking about is the *second* example, where he adds the `WHILE` loop (equivalent to a cursor) after the first example didn't update all rows, only one, like the answer above - because both were written with the assumption that only one row would ever be deleted at a time. The problem here has nothing to do with RBAR, is all I was getting at.

Comment: @Aaron: from my point of view, RBAR = the procedural way. Reading one row from a set or reading a row and then the second row, the third row and so represent the procedural way. More, reading only one row from a set (having many rows) also shows this way of thinking. Also, from my poiny of view the first two  `dbo.TR_Employees_A_I_FlagNewEmployees[_Multirows]` triggers are both RBAR in different ways. Regarding first trigger, the author states "So what is RBAR in a trigger? Let's say that you want to set a flag to true with all new inserted rows. The RBAR code could look something like this".

Comment: Ok, you keep calling that RBAR; I will not. Let's agree to disagree, because I don't think I'm going to be able to convince you otherwise... you've read one person who allegedly called that method RBAR, so that must be RBAR. <shrug>